# Por que fatorial acima de 170 retorna infinito?

Tags: php

Fiz este código php para calcular o fatorial de números inteiros positivos , porém , para números a partir de 170 o resultado é sempre infinito e gostaria de entender o porque disso.

ex3

```
 $numero_usuario = isset($_POST['a'])?$_POST['a']:0;
 $fatorial = $numero_usuario;

 if($numero_usuario == 0){
   echo $numero_usuario;
 }
 if($numero_usuario > 0){
   while($fatorial!=1){
       $fatorial--;
       $numero_usuario *= $fatorial;

   }
   echo $numero_usuario;
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Porque os tipos numéricos tem um limite máximo, e se o cálculo ultrapassa esse limite, o resultado é "infinito"

Comment: 171! = 1.2 × 10^309 > 1.8e308 (o máximo valor de double) (https://www.wolframalpha.com/). Se você precisa calcular fatoriais grandes, vai precisar de número de ponto flutuante com precisão arbitrária. Mas se você está calculando arranjos e combinações, calcule os quocientes primeiro.

Comment: (e adicione um epsilon no final para corrigir o arredondamento do processador).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249677/factorial-of-170) você pode encontrar uma resposta sobre isso, que eu adaptei e adicionei algumas coisas que encontrei pesquisando:

O que acontece é que você está ultrapassando a precisão de um `double` em um sistema 64bits. Essa [precisão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) varia entre `10^−308` e `10^308`. Em valores aproximados:

- Fatorial de 170: `7.25741562 * 10^307` (dentro do limite de precisão)
- Fatorial de 171: `1.24101807 * 10^309` (fora do limite de precisão, então "infinito")

Então é recomendado você utilizar uma extensão capaz de fazer esse tipo de multiplicação. Uma das possibilidades é a **[BCMath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)** (*BCMath Arbitrary Precision Mathematics*), que foi a que encontrei o pessoal utilizando para multiplicação de valores grandes (com a função [`bcmul`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php)).

Adaptando seu código:

```php
while($fatorial!=1){
    $fatorial--;
    $numero_usuario = bcmul($numero_usuario, $fatorial);
}
```

---

Fato interessante: pesquise pelo fatorial de [170](https://www.google.com/search?hl=pt-BR&source=hp&ei=LyyaXqWIBPW_5OUP7OKimAk&q=170%21&oq=170%21&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzICCAAyBQgAEIMBMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCABQ-gVYhgtghAxoAHAAeACAAaMBiAHHA5IBAzIuMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjl28Tlv_DoAhX1H7kGHWyxCJMQ4dUDCAc&uact=5) no Google e depois pelo fatorial de [171](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk0111DpflCaeTWR1r-Vi5pcfyU-Fng%3A1587162182180&ei=RiyaXrieCobB5OUPs_2woAw&q=171%21&oq=171%21&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzIECAAQQzIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHlDgCFjgCGDUC2gAcAB4AIABogGIAe8CkgEDMS4ymAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi42cbwv_DoAhWGILkGHbM-DMQQ4dUDCAw&uact=5):

[image: O Google calcula o Fatorial de 170 porém exibe Undefined para 171!]

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!!

Answer (score -1):

O fatorial com um valor baixo já retorna um valor muito alto, veja

10! = 3.628.800

170 está ultrapassando o limite de memória de alocação estipulado pela Linguagem de Programação.

Veja o exemplo da Linguagem C:
pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C/Tipos_de_dados

As demais linguagens seguem da mesma maneira, mas cada uma com o seu tamanho de alocação específico.

Comment: `170!` Não ultrapassa o limite de memória da máquina, não faz nem cosquinha(diminutivo de cosca, forma sincopada de cócega).

Comment: Pode até ser que o da memória RAM não, mas excede o espaço do tamanho que a Linguagem de Programação usa para alocar a variável na memória. Cada tipo variável tem um tamanho máximo suportado. 

Veja um exemplo da linguagem C:
https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C/Tipos_de_dados

No entanto, todas as linguagens possuem as suas limitações.

Comment: É isso que tem que ser explicado na resposta. Da maneira que escreveu dá a entender que o fatorial consumiu toda a RAM.

Comment: Sim, me expressei errado. Obrigado pela comentário Augusto Vasques. Informação corrigida.